# Is healing with honey mentioned in the Bible?

Tags: bible, healing, healthcare

From [webmd](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-738-honey.aspx?activeingredientid=738)

> Honey’s healing properties are mentioned in the Bible, Koran, and Torah.

Is is true that the Bible talks about healing with honey? What does the Bible say about honey's healing properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bible repeatedly refers to honey as a good thing – for example, the land promised to the Israelites is regularly referred to as "a land flowing with milk and honey" (e.g., [Exodus 3:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+3:8&version=ESV)).  But in such cases honey is more clearly a reference to wealth or sweetness, not necessarily physical healing.

The clearest connection between honey and physical healing is probably in [Proverbs 16:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+16:24&version=ESV):

> Gracious words are like a honeycomb, sweetness to the soul and health to the body. (ESV)

More frequently, honey is sustenance that physically benefits people.  For example, Jonathan's "eyes became bright" after eating honey in [1 Samuel 14:24–30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Samuel+14%3A24%E2%80%9330&version=ESV).  Honey also sustains people in passages like [Deuteronomy 32:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+32:13&version=ESV), [2 Samuel 17:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Samuel+17:29&version=ESV), [Psalm 81:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+81:16&version=ESV), [Ezekiel 16:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel+16:13&version=ESV), and [Matthew 3:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+3:4&version=ESV).

On the other hand, eating too much is warned against in [Proverbs 25:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs+25:16&version=ESV):

> If you have found honey, eat only enough for you, lest you have your fill of it and vomit it.

A complete list of references to honey in the Bible can be found by using a concordance, or an online tool like [Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=honey&qs_version=ESV&limit=100).